# rails devise not logged in for particular page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

when i sign in it redirects to the root page, but here in the navbar(header) if user_signed in ? function is not executed, but in other pages lets say /browse/audi in the header it shows the username with logout, rest of the pages identifies that user has logged in except but the landing page

```
 caches_page :index

layout 'application_slide', only: [:index]
layout 'car_model', only: [:car_model]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: "step2"
```

My controller for the root_path (i.e, index)

```
def index
if user_signed_in?
  if current_user.role == "dealer"
    redirect_to dashboard_dealer_path
  else
    #@carmake = Carmake.search(params[:makename])asd
    #    @carmodel = Car.search(params[:makename])
    #@zipcode = Profile.search(params[:search])
    @makes = DivisionDefinition.order(:division_name)
    ................
    ................
    ................
    ................
    end
  end
end
```

My layout for index

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Nabthat" %></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin" %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body class="login-layout off-canvas hide-extras" id="common-nav" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
 <%= render "/layouts/navbar" %>
 <%# render "/layouts/flash" %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
    <div class="main-container-inner">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My navbar

```
    <% if !user_signed_in? %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Log in", "#nav-login-modal",:data => {"toggle" => "modal"}, class: "li-pull-right"%>  
    </li><li>
      <%= link_to "List Your Dealership", new_user_registration_path, class: "list-dealer-new nav-list-dealer"%>
    </li>
    <% else %>
```

For index action alone it shows the login link in navbar as if i'm not logged in but if i go to any other page it shows user name

While checking with curl for this error (diffrence b/w root and other page)

root_page

```
➜  nthat git:(master) ✗ curl -I https://nabthat.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 10:18:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 21392
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 09:04:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "52ef5b94-5390"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

➜  nthat git:(master) ✗ curl -I https://nabthat.com/browse-car/Audi
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 10:18:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 39651
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "659ad8caeff9e921ced5ef8e3fa0d266"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: request_method=GET; path=/
X-Request-Id: 30d83bc2f036eedffe1a8fdb1be7405b
X-Runtime: 0.363171
X-Rack-Cache: miss
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your user model it should be **user.rb** not users.rb

Otherwise you can use **current_user** method for checking the user logged in or not

Comment: My model name is user.rb, user_signed_in? is working in rest of the pages except root_path(i.e landing page)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `caches_page :index` is caching the page before you sign in.  Then when you are signed in, the cached page is returned without checking with your rails app server (so never has a chance to check if you're signed in) - nginx just returns it directly (which would explain why the response headers received by curl are so different).

If this is the case, you could resolve it by removing the `caches_page :index`.  If you really need to cache your index page, you can wrap however much of the index view you want in a `<% cache do %> … <% end %>` block (possibly not much as it looks like there's dynamic stuff happening in your index view too - e.g. the role check).  Alternatively you might want to use action caching or the new Rails 4 caching approach if you're on Rails 4.

Rails 3.2 caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/caching_with_rails.html

Rails 4 caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html